# WPS "Hello World" example in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wps

I've been searching for a good example of how to publish a Web Process Service (WPS) on the GeoServer platform.  The [page where you'd think they'd document](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps/index.html) this process is actually pretty thin.

There's some documentation on [implementing an OWS service](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/ows-services/implementing.html), but I am unsure what the conceptual and implementation overlap is between OWS and WPS in GeoServer.

Is anyone aware of a good example of implementing a WPS on GeoServer?

Comment: `I am unsure what the conceptual and implementation overlap is between OWS and WPS`.  OWS is generic, a WPS is a type of OWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Geoserver published a guide on how to implement a WPS.  It can be found [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had the following discussion with Andrea on the user's list a while back http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Add-a-WPS-process-to-GeoServer-td6112468.html but I haven't had the time to follow it up (or document it as I promised) as I still have bugs in my code to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the discussion. I am however still struggeling with this. Is there maybe any new info anyone can provide me with, surronding this? Is there a good GeoServer dev blog somewhere out there?